# How to specify a custom frontend_model inside Magento's admin interface

Tags: magento

My question is essentially the same as this one:
[Add a date picker to system.xml on custom module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660842/add-a-date-picker-to-system-xml-on-custom-module/10411804)

I'd like to add a customer frontend_model to support a date picker in Magento's admin configuration.

When I try to follow the steps in the linked post, I get an empty screen.  I can see in my system.log that "Mage/" is included at the front of the file-path.  Normally this would imply an improper config.xml for the relevant module, but everything I've read on frontend_model doesn't have it registered in the config.

When adding a custom frontend_model, is it necessary to register the block in config.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to register a custom front_end model.  It is necessary to reference the model by the name provided for the module.